# Iam trying to make a app with react native and i want to implement a bottom navigation bar

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make an app with react native and I want to implement a bottom navigation bar, all I find are tab bars that work like stack push and pop, I want to replace the screen entirely. Help anyone?

Comment: [React Navigation Bottom Tab Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/).

Comment: @yudhiesh as I said I do not want to push a screen on the stack, I want to replace it

Comment: Make your custom navigation and you can achieve this

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "replace the screen entirely"? Any UI that you can show us?